# Two conditions into a single one

Tags: javascript

I have written this code and I'm trying to optimize it.

```
            if (imageEntity.get('image').get('value')[480]) {
                sliderImages.push('<div style="opacity: ' + ((index === 0)? 1 : 0) + '; transition: opacity .5s ease; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(./../../connect/img/user-images/' + imageEntity.get('image').get('value')[480]+'?_='+Date.now() + ') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>');
            } else if (imageEntity.get('image').get('value')[150]){
                sliderImages.push('<div style="opacity: ' + ((index === 0)? 1 : 0) + '; transition: opacity .5s ease; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(./../../connect/img/user-images/' + imageEntity.get('image').get('value')[150]+'?_='+Date.now() + ') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>');
            } else {
                sliderImages.push('<div style="opacity: ' + ((index === 0)? 1 : 0) + '; transition: opacity .5s ease; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(img/ctrl-thumb.png) center center no-repeat; background-color: #f6f6f6;"></div>');
            }
```

How can I combine sliderImages.Push into one? There is `imageEntity.get('image').get('value')[150]+'?_='+Date.now() +`  how can i put 480 or 150 based on what is available?

Thanks

Comment: Haven't you heard of boolean operators??

Comment: Have you tried using the `||` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this piece of code. In JavaScript you may conditionally set a variable like so.

```
var x = new Object();
var y = (window.i || window.x);
```

In the above case, the variable "i" is undefined, but the variable "x" is not. Setting the the variable "y" using an evaluation as shown above makes "y" set to the value for "x" because "i" is undefined. However, be forewarned that the following does not work:

```
var x = new Object();
var y = (i || x);
```

For the evaluation to succeed, you need to use the variables as members of some other object. That said, it may be possible to revise your code like so:

```
var i = (imageEntity.get('image').get('value')[480] || imageEntity.get('image').get('value')[150]);
if(!i){
    sliderImages.push('<div style="opacity: ' + ((index === 0) ? 1 : 0) + '; transition: opacity .5s ease; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(img/ctrl-thumb.png) center center no-repeat; background-color: #f6f6f6;"></div>');
}else{
    sliderImages.push('<div style="opacity: ' + ((index === 0) ? 1 : 0) + '; transition: opacity .5s ease; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(./../../connect/img/user-images/' + i + '?_=' + Date.now() + ') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = imageEntity.get('image').get('value')[480] || imageEntity.get('image').get('value')[150];
if (image) {
    sliderImages.push('<div style="opacity: ' + ((index === 0)? 1 : 0) + '; transition: opacity .5s ease; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(./../../connect/img/user-images/' + image + '?_=' + Date.now() + ') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>');
} else {
    sliderImages.push('<div style="opacity: ' + ((index === 0)? 1 : 0) + '; transition: opacity .5s ease; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(img/ctrl-thumb.png) center center no-repeat; background-color: #f6f6f6;"></div>');
}
```

You should use CSS classes for your `div` and set only the dynamic values via JavaScript.

Comment: imageEntity.get('image').get('value')[480]+'?_='+Date.now() how can i insert 480 or 150 based on what is available? That's what i wanted to know

Comment: Edited my answer. The `image` variable will either contain a value (if one is set) or be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not repeat what you're repeating...

```
var img = imageEntity.get( 'image' );
if ( img.get('value')[480] || img.get('value')[150] ) {}
```